# How can I order a file line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have to make a code that will produce a GUI that shows test results for three classes and all the information will be on a file. I have tried to do the code I can make the GUI and radio buttons and that all works, but get a button that allows you to put what ever is in the text box to be in alphabetical order.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Test scores")
root.geometry("500x300")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
test1 = open("names.txt","r")
test2 = open("score.txt","r")
test3 = open("class.txt","r")
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self,
              text = "Which class "
              ).grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = W)
        Label(self,
              text = "Select a class"
              ).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.choose = StringVar()
        self.choose.set(None)
        Radiobutton(self,
               text = "Class 1",
               variable = self.choose,
               value = test1.read(), 
               command = self.update_text
               ).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.second = BooleanVar()
        Radiobutton(self,
               text = "Class 2",
               variable = self.choose,
               value = test2.read(),     
               command = self.update_text
               ).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.third = BooleanVar()
        Radiobutton(self,
               text = "Class 3",
               variable = self.choose,
               value = test3.read(),     
               command = self.update_text
               ).grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.bttn = Button(self)
        self.bttn["text"] = "Alphabetical"
        self.bttn["command"] = self.update_order
        self.bttn.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.results_txt = Text(self, width = 40, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.results_txt.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

    def update_text(self):
        likes = ""
        likes += self.choose.get()
        self.results_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.results_txt.insert(0.0, likes)

    def update_order(self):
        sortfile = open("sorted1.txt","w")
        for line in sorted(self.results_txt, key = str.lower):
            sortfile.write(line)



app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

this is my code so far.

i tried to sort it but it doesn't work this is the code i tried as i looked online and saw this

```
def update_order(self):
        str(sorted(self.results_txt, key=lambda student: student[2]))
```

how would i sort file lines
so if the first line had "name" "first score" "second score" "third score"
then on the second line "different name" "first score" "second score" "third score"
how would you sort it alphabetically by the name in the line nothing else. would i need to put each score on different files?

Comment: Which version of Tkinter do you have installed? Making only two changes to your code and using Tkinter `'$Revision: 81008 $'`, your code works for me: the text box gets updated. Changes I made were: `from Tkinter import *` (mind the capital letter) and `class Application(Frame, object):` to get a new style class under Python2.7.

Comment: i dont know what version i have how do you find out

Comment: `import Tkinter as tk; print(tk.__version__)` . It's very common among lots of Python modules to list their version numbers under the module's `__version__` attribute.

Comment: it doesn't like (T)kinter the capital letter

Comment: Then you have a different version from me (in Python3.x, a lot of modules were rewritten to comply with PEP8, tkinter is one of them: the capital letter was lowercased). Import tkinter the way you did it in your code.

Comment: Just mentioning here that, using the same code I used before, but changing the `from Tkinter import *` to `from tkinter import *` and using Python3.3, the code still works.

Comment: Do the files `names.txt`, `score.txt` and `class.txt` actually have *any content*? Under Python3.3, your code, as it was, works well on my side.

Comment: where do you install tkinter